# RimhTypingLetters and Bad Access

Tags: swift

I just started to learn iOS development. I have 3 screens (Launch, Second and Main). I have a ViewController for Second (screen). I installed [RimhTypingLetters](https://github.com/rimh/RimhTypingLetters) library with CocaoPods. I think I did installed properly because I can access library's methods and Xcode automatically recognizes methods but when I simply try to use this library I get this error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x200000003)
```

I don't need any button or something to trigger typing letters. I just want to run it automatically when the screen loaded.

**Pod File:**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'MyApp' do
pod 'RimhTypingLetters'
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp


end

workspace 'MyApp'
```

**Second.swift**

```
import UIKit
import RimhTypingLetters


class Second: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView1: TypingLetterUITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 7) {
            let main = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let mainVC = main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainVC")
            self.present(mainVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        typeTheText()

    }

    func typeTheText() {
        let message = "Something.."
        self.textView1.typeText(message) {
            print("printed")
        }
    }

}
```

Also I don't understand why I cannot access UI elements outside of viewDidLoad directly, I mean why do I need to use a function?

Comment: 1. Which line exactly is causing the error? 2. Why are you presenting another view controller 7 seconds after `viewDidLoad` is called? 3. What does your last sentence in your question mean?

Comment: 1. `self.textView1.typeText(message) {`  this line is causing the error. 2. I want to show some text, after 7 seconds, I want to pass my main screen. 3. I mean for example why textView1 is not accessible outside of viewDidLoad(). If I delete the func tpyeTheText(), I cannot access the textView1 element. Why? I am just wondering.

Comment: Can you confirm that your `textView1` is properly connected to your element on storyboard?

Comment: @manman yes because I can see the circle is full and when I click the full circle it forwards me the textview on the storyboard. Also connection inspector shows my textView1 is referencing Second (ViewController)

Comment: @TToprak1 Would need more info then in order to be able to point out what's wrong as usually the common mistake is misconnecting view controllers and ui elements in code and storyboard. If you can share your code somewhere, will be more than happy to review and point out where the issue is.

Comment: @manman you mean all project or all viewcontrollers etc? Also one more thing. I am using .xcworkspace. but when I try to run my .xcodeproj, xCode says that `No such module 'RimhTypingLetters'`. Should I work on .xcodeproj or .xcworkspace?

Comment: The whole project. `.xcworkspace` is the one that you'd need to use. That's generated during `pod install` which takes care of linking your dependencies and your application (targets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what's going wrong, you have changed your `UITextView` to be an instance of `TypingLetterUITextView` in your view controller, but haven't set it in interface builder to be of this type. For this you need to do following steps in your `main.storyboard` file:

1. Find your view controller and then find the `TextView` element there and select it.
2. Select the identity inspector and then enter `TypingLetterUITextView` for the class name.